# Search formula fields using SOSL

Tags: visualforce, formula, sosl

Im trying to build a custom job board search on visualforce.  I have a positions object which has a relationship has a master detail field to account.

I'd like the search to return positions when you search for company (account names).  I know you can use SOSL to search multiple sObject types but id rather it always just return positions.  So i made a simple formula field just pulling the org name to the position but it doesnt seem to work.

When i create a text field and then have a trigger fill that in that works fine.. but the trigger feels a lot messier...

is there a way to do this with formulas that will work?  or better yet is there a way to search all the "related" fields and still return the specific object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it looks to be [undocumented](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/), formula fields do not appear to be supported by SOSL.

> The search() call searches most objects (including custom objects) and
>   text fields to which you have access. It does not search the following
>   objects and fields:
>
> - Any elements such as picklists that are defined as not searchable (searchable is false). To determine whether a given object is
>     searchable, your application can invoke the describeSObjects() call on
>     the object and inspect the searchable property in the
>     DescribeSObjectResult.
> - Number, date, or checkbox fields. To search for such information, use the query() call instead.
> - Textarea fields, unless you use the ALL FIELDS search group.
> - Attachment records associated with certain objects, such as Account, Contact, or Opportunity.

While triggers and apex sound like quite a lot of overhead, at this point it looks to be the only option to mimic formula field behavior to create a searchable field on your child records.

Comment: Usually in such case I create a text(255) ext. id field and a simple workflow that synchronizes the value from formula field to the text field on insert & every update. Or just delete the formula field completely and keep the formula only in the field update definition. Bonus points: it makes possible to use the text field in `GROUP BY` which is impossible with formulas.

Comment: how do you update all childs when the parent value change with a workflow ?

Comment: As long as the formula on child doesn't need any fields from the parent you're fine, right? But if you do - yes, a simple trigger would be needed. Identify `Set<id>` of accounts on which one of fields referenced in formula have changed and just "touch" them: `update [SELECT Id FROM Child__c WHERE Account__c IN :changedSet];`. Workflow will take care of actual update.